# How to create connection among state, city, store and store number based on URL

Tags: custom-post-types, urls

I'm about creating a store in which I have state, city, store, and store number, so what is the best way to create a connection among them? Is that okay if I create CPT with name store then create taxonomy state, city and store number?
actually, i also want the URL should be like

```
example.com/state/city/store-numebr/store
```

i.e

```
example.come/alabama/muscleshoals/8042788/liberty-tax-al-muscle-shoals
```

so what's the best way to create relations which help me create the same URL above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you already have the answer. The thing I would recommend is to create a CPT called Store. That will give you the capability of having something like:

`example.com/store/store-name`

Being `store` the name of your CPT.

Now with the taxonomy:

### First approach: Just one taxonomy

Now, you would create a custom taxonomy for the CPT, maybe called `store_category` and have the states, cities and store numbers being created as terms under this category,  hierarchically.

The problem with this approach is that creating the permalink structure will be difficult since there is no way to specify a top level or second level term inside the permalink. So I would opt for the second approach.

### Second Approach: multiple Taxonomies

I would create one taxonomy called `state`, one called `city` and one called `store_number`. This may seem overhead but this will give you a logic separation between one type of taxonomy and the other. Once this is ready, now you would only need to `hack` the permalinks for this CPT to get the url structure you are looking for.

In general, you now should have the capability to define a permalink structure like:

`example.com/%state%/%city%/%store_number%/%post_name%`

This could be achieve with a plugin like **Custom Post Type Permalinks** [Custom Post Type Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/)

I think this is the best way to get this relationship going.

Comment: 2nd approach make sense, i will follow that one much appreciated your reply thanks, Answer accepted :) i have one more question i will write some coding logic for that but maybe you have a better solution for that, with the 2nd approach like i have taxonomy state, city, and store number so on the front-end page i called/showed all states in (ul li) list with permalinks, so i know when i click any of the states it will redirect me to the template taxonomy-state.php alright so now how i will fetch all cities inside that state? do you have any easy wp-query arguments for that? or easy logic?